# GitLab: I can't push or clone repo, asking for Git password

Tags: git, ssh, passwords, gitlab

I have installed latest GitLab with Bitnami. But I can't push my updates to central repo. It always asks for Git password. I installed it in a local server and given the domain name as a local IP. The public keys are updated in /hom/git/.ssh/authorised_keys list. Iut it asks for Git user password. Please, help me.

Comment: can you ping that domain name from the client? What client do you have? (Windows, Unix?) What version of `git` do you have on the client? Do you see `gitlab-shell` in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server?

Comment: I've been struggling with this for months. Take a look at this github issue. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/search?q=1875

Comment: later i tried gitlab 4.2 with no bitnami and it works fine. the gitlab 5 has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

it is strange. Could you check that your SSH server is configured to use authorized_keys files?

> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>
> PubkeyAuthentication yes

Could you check the file permissions for the .ssh/authorized_keys file? The owner should be the git user. Did you already have a Gitlab version installed before? Maybe Gitolite is already installed and you need to use gitlab-shell for GitLab 5.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that your git command is something like this

```
 git clone git@domain:project.git
```

or maybe

```
 sudo git clone git@domain:project.git
```

Sometimes we get mixed up with the user account that we are using. If we run `sudo`, that means the command is being run as root. And did you create the SSH key for root and put it in Gitlab? In other case you probably created the SSH key using `sudo ssh-keygen` but you run git normally, meaning the git command is running as the active user.

We may also get mixed up with the SSH key that we put inside Gitlab.

Not sure if you need this yet, but if you use web hook, in Ubuntu the Apache is normally running as www-data. So for web hook to work, you would need to create SSH key for the www-data user.

Answer (score 0):

I just setup gitlab yesterday on a virtual machine (xenserver) and ubuntu server 12.x LTS. I had the same exact issue.

I set my ssh keys and all that, still nothing.

I did 2 things, not sure if one or both fixed it...

First, I installed git (!). I just assumed it would come with gitlab, but it didn't.

```bash
sudo apt-get install git
```

When you install gitlab, it creates a user 'git', though, it doesn't show up in the home dir.

I set a password for git user:

```bash
sudo passwd git
```

I restart the machine after that. I was then able to push / pull like so:

```bash
git clone git@192.168.1.182:test-group/test-repo.git
```

I want to use git / gitlab to deploy automatic and remote updates for many, many machines at remote locations. I still can't figure out how to do it. I thought you could create a user in gitlab and push/pull based off that users permissions but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Good luck!